# Multiplication using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I want to multiply the unit price by the quantity from the text box and it needs to keep on changing while I change the value of the text box.

```
<div>
    <label id="" name="price" class="unitprice"><?php echo "Price: <label id = hprice> LKR Rs ".$price.".00 </label> /item" ?></label>
</div>

<label id="lbl"> Quantity:</label>

<div class="quantity buttons_added" id="qtybox">
  <input type="button" value="-" class="minus" id= "minus">
  <input type="text" step="1" min="1" max="<?php echo $qty?>" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" id="tqty" size="4" pattern="" inputmode="">
  <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" id="plus">
  <label id="pcs"><?php echo "Piece(s) (".$qty. " pieces available)"?></label>
</div>
</br>
<label>Total:</label>
<p id="total"> 0</p>
```

Comment: How does this question have anything at all to do with Ajax?  Ajax is for server communication.... are you suggesting that you need your server to help do this simplistic math??

Answer (score 0):

Create one text box where the user will enter values for quantity and another <div> for displaying the final price.

In the script on a keyup event it will read the value of the `qty` textbox and multiply it with the price which is 100 for now and displays the final price in the <div> tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='qty' id='qtity'>
<div id='final_price'></div>
<script>
  var price=100;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qtity').keyup(function () {
        var qty=this.value
        $('#final_price').html(price*qty);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how AJAX does anything for you as AJAX only handles the communication. You're still in charge of displaying the information.

If you mean jQuery which is often paired with AJAX, I think you are better off using a MVC library such as Angular or Vue.js. My example is done in Vue.js:

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el : "#root",
  data : {
    units: 0,
    price: 0.0
  },
  computed : {
    totalPrice : function() {
      return this.units * this.price;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <label> Units: </label> <br>
  <input v-model="units" type="number" step="1" min="0"> <br>
  <label> Price: </label> <br>
  <input v-model="price" type="number" step=".01" min="0">

  <p>  $ {{ totalPrice }} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: For what reason could my answer be worthy of a -1.  Besides the fact that I tell the OP that Ajax can't do what they want, which is the truth...  Can't improve without feedback.